# Given two variables and their ranges, get a third value.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'm building a model but I got stuck at this:

I have $x,y$ whose ranges are ($10,000$ to $2,000,000$) and (1 to 36) respectively. Also I have a z that ranges from 16 to 30. I know their relations in certain cases. I know that when:

Case 1: $X=10,000$ and $Y=1$ then $Z=16$ //When $X$ and $Y$ are at their lower ranges, then $Z$ is at it's low

Case 2: $X=2,000,000$ and $Y=36$ then $Z=30$ //When $X$ and $Y$ are at their top ranges, then $Z$ is at it's top

Case 3: $X=1,005,000$ and $Y=18.5$ then $Z=23$ //The middle

Given this how could I make an equation system correctly that given $X$,$Y$ I get $Z$?

I tried using case 1 and 2 for a two variable solution (using $Z$ as a constant, didn't worked), then I tried using the three cases as equations but the same.
Don't know if this is too low level for this site but google searches gave me no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have these two points (we don't need the 3rd)

$(10000,1,16)$ and 
$(2000000,36,30)$

you can think of it this way:

$$z = \alpha x + \beta y$$
$$16 = \alpha * 10000 + \beta $$
$$30 = \alpha * 2000000 + \beta *36$$

Solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ($\frac{-273}{820000}$ and $\frac{1585}{82}$ respectively I think)

Then, you're done.

Comment: Just think in 3 dimensional space. the system of equations you have defined above really describe a LINE in 3D space, which you don't need 3 points to describe, but just two.

Comment: Then for example if I use α = 2000000 and β = 1 my z = -646.52 which would be out of my z range... this means that with my line those two values are in a different part of the space... is that right?

Comment: Then I guess my model is wrong as I need both ranges to be viable solutions.

Comment: @luisescamilla the final answer would be: 
$z = \frac{-273}{820000}x + \frac{1585}{82}y$. I tried the 3rd point and I believe it works. I think you substituted the alpha and beta wrong

Comment: You think? I double checked and still got the same: ((-273/820000)*2000000)+((1585/82)*1) = -646.52

Comment: @luisescamilla "Case 3: X=1,005,000 and Y=18.5 then Z=23"
"Case 2: X=2,000,000 and Y=36"

Comment: You're right, it works. Thanks man!